# Validate date in Jquery

Tags: jquery, postgresql, validation, date, yii

I'm developing in Yii and i'm using Bootstrap extensions for my date picker. And i'm a beginner in Jquery

I'm specifically using bootstrap datePicker Row to save into my postgres database a "date" type of value.

I have two date picker rows to pick two dates:

> 1. the first one should range from the present date until next year + 1 only. (e.g. today upto Dec 30, 2014).
> 2. And the second should be ahead of the first date by atleast a day upto next year + 1.

Postgres values "date" is in the format "2013-10-18", (year-month-day). And so goes for the datepicker.

My first idea was to actually parse the strings to get the year month and day. like:

```
$firstDate = $(#first-date-input).val();
$secondDate = $(#second-date-input).val();
$firstDate = explode("-",$date);
$firstYear = $firstDate[0];
$firstMonth = $firstDate[1];
$firstDay = $firstDate[2];
```

and then do some other comparisons, but this is too long to do and too inefficient. I was hoping to get ideas on how to do this neatly and not too hardcoded in Jquery by some functions perhaps? Any good ideas? Thanks!

Comment: And if i'm correct you want to validate it after (for example) submission of a form or if the datepicker field changes? If so, you can write your own validation rules: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: This is actually useful, but i've yet to understand RegEx... anyway, thanks for the tip

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use RegEx for it. You can create your own method in your model and use that method (function) as a validation rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying to parse the date first...

```
 var theDate = Date.parse($('#first-date-input').val());
//add a year
var nextYear = new Date(theDate);
nextYear.setDate(nextYear.getDate()+ 365);
```

Then you can do all kinds of standard comparisons... `< ... >=` ...